# Want to adjust/replace front fork suspension on a Next Break Point pro 26" bike. Has no access at the axle.

Tags: fork, suspension, front

Very 'low end' fork, bottoms are pinched at axle point, so no access there. Is there a way to clean, adjust these or is fork replacement my only option?

Comment: The 'very low end' forks are replaced with the suspension, as the work to replace the suspension isn't worth it. I pretty sure you even can't find springs for these forks.

Comment: This is a BSO. Don't bother unless you have a very very good reason.

Comment: If the bike is rideable, trade it in on a replacement bike.  Will work out cheaper than part-upgrading the existing one piece by piece.

Answer (score 1):

Low end forks are generally not repairable. The primary reason is that spare parts are not readily available. They can however be serviced. The labor involved would make it prohibitive to pay for the service as it will likely exceed the forks' value. Most can be disassembled, cleaned and greased. Remove (read this as pry) the plastic caps on the upper legs. With a flashlight you should see an allen head screw (5mm head) very deep in the fork. To loosen it requires either a very long wrench or a 3/8 drive allen socket and a long extension. Back off both screw evenly keeping track of the number of turns. Back off the screw until the lower section separates. You can clean any rust from the section and apply a general purpose grease to the moving parts. Then reassemble tightening the screws the same number of turns they were loosened. Just remember this is just service not a repair. Any parts that were worn are still worn.